# How to start coundowntimer from it sttoped in android?

Tags: android

I have a countdown timer for 30 seconds with progressbar which works fine,but when app goes in pause state timer still works but I want when app goes in pause state timer and progress bar will stop and when resume app it will start from where it stop. how can I do that.

here is my code:-

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void init() {// initialize view controls

    m_timerProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pb);// finding ID of progressbar

    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);// finding Id of textview to show timer text
    tv.setText("00:00");// set timer text
    //Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
    long m_MillisInFuture = 30000;// timer value
    long m_CountDownInterval = 1000;// timer break up
    m_oTimer = new CountDownTimer(m_MillisInFuture, m_CountDownInterval) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            tv.setText(hms);
            //Another one second passed
            //Each second ProgressBar progress counter added one
            m_n_ProgressStatus += 1;
            m_timerProgress.setProgress(m_n_ProgressStatus);
        }

        public void onFinish() {// when timer finished

            Intent i = new Intent(COtpAutoVerificationScreen.this, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }.start();// start timer
    // retreive progress bar count........
    int progressBarMaximumValue = (int) (m_MillisInFuture / m_CountDownInterval);
    //Set ProgressBar maximum value
    //ProgressBar range (0 to maximum value)
    m_timerProgress.setMax(progressBarMaximumValue);
    //Display the CountDownTimer initial value
    tv.setText(progressBarMaximumValue + "Seconds...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In onPause cancel the timer. Use global variable to keep track of time. As timer runs reduce the global variable by the interval.

In onResume start countdown timer with Global variable as timer value. Your progress bar also you can save last position and start manipulating from there.

```
private long currentMillis=30000;
```

change your init method to take a long parameter and move your initialization of views outside

```
private void init( long millis) {

//Initialize a new CountDownTimer instance
long m_MillisInFuture = millis;// timer value
long m_CountDownInterval = 1000;// timer break up
m_oTimer = new CountDownTimer(m_MillisInFuture, m_CountDownInterval) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") long millis = millisUntilFinished;

   long hmsLong=,
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -                    TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished));
        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d",TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),hmsLong );
        System.out.println(hms);
        currentMillis=hmsLong;
        tv.setText(hms);
        //Another one second passed
        //Each second ProgressBar progress counter added one
        m_n_ProgressStatus += 1;
        m_timerProgress.setProgress(m_n_ProgressStatus);
    }
         .....
     m_oTimer.start();
```

then your OnPause should be as

```
        @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    m_oTimer.cancel();
    }
```

and onResume will be

```
             @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    init(currentMillis)
    }
```

This should do what you want.

Comment: where to call init(with parameter)

Comment: in onResume. Whenever your app runs onResume will be called.

Comment: it never start with where it stop it

Comment: I have edited my answer. Just add m_oTimer.start() as the last line inside init method.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can achieve this by following steps.
make m_MillisInFuture member variable

public void OnPause(){ 
    m_oTimer.stop();
    m_oTimer = null;
    m_MillisInFuture- = m_n_ProgressStatus*1000;
}

public void onResume(){
    //here create your timer with updated m_MillisInFuture value and start
    startTimer();


}

    private void startTimer(){
        m_oTimer = new CountDownTimer(m_MillisInFuture, m_CountDownInterval) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            @SuppressWarnings("UnusedAssignment") long millis = millisUntilFinished;
            @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished),
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
            System.out.println(hms);
            tv.setText(hms);
            //Another one second passed
            //Each second ProgressBar progress counter added one
            m_n_ProgressStatus += 1;
            m_timerProgress.setProgress(m_n_ProgressStatus);
        }

        public void onFinish() {// when timer finished

            Intent i = new Intent(COtpAutoVerificationScreen.this, COtpManualVerificationScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    }.start();

    }
```

Comment: what is m_MillisInFuture- ,there is minus sign or what

Comment: minus sign! this is your code.I just copy and paste it here